# Finding the nth element of a list in scala recursively with pattern matching

Tags: list, scala, recursion, pattern-matching

I have a problem here from 99 scala problems (http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p03.scala) that I am trying to figure out how it works. I'm fairly new to Scala. I was able to complete this challenge with a similar solution using pattern matching and recursion however mine did not consider the list in the matching. My code is below:

```
def nth[A](k: Int, l: List[A]): A = k match {
  case 0 => l.head
  case _ => nth(k-1, l.drop(1))
}
```

and this seemed to do the job. However, there's no error checking if the list is Nil. The solution 99 scala problems provides is:

```
def nthRecursive[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): A = (n, ls) match {
  case (0, h :: _   ) => h
  case (n, _ :: tail) => nthRecursive(n - 1, tail)
  case (_, Nil      ) => throw new NoSuchElementException
}
```

What I dont understand is

```
case(0, h:: _ )
```

and

```
case(n, _ :: tail)
```

What is the author doing here? I understand :: appends whatever is on the left to the beginning of whats on the right but I'm not sure exactly what is happening. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :: operator is used to extract the head and the rest of the list (the tail).

Here:

```
case(0, h :: _ )
```

only the head is relevant so the tail doesn't get a reference.

And Here:

```
case(n, _ :: tail)
```

only the tail is relevant so the head doesn't get a reference.

You can also use:

```
case(0, head :: tail)
case(n, head :: tail)
```

(i.e. giving both parts a reference) and get exactly the same result.

Comment: So basically since _ is the wildcard (matching anything) but doesn't actually store something the match will only store the head and ignore the tail? That's interesting. I wonder why that syntax isn't covered in the list documentation on the Scala website.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is **pattern matching expression**. That is why Scala pattern matching is so powerful, so we can drop some heavy visitor pattern like Java (out of this topic).

A simple example:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)

def doStuff(user: User) = user match {
  case User(_, age) if age > 100 => println("Impossible!")
  case User(name, _) => println("hello " + name)
}
```

In this case, _ :: tail just means I want to get the reference of the tail.